# Replacing NA`s with 0 or space depending on the position of the `NA` in a string

Tags: regex, r

I have a data frame with a million of long strings which contains 0, 1, NA`s.

I have to replace NA`s based on the following method:

1. all of the NA at the end of the string has to be replaced with space
2. all of the NA at the middle of the string has to be changed to 0.

Example:
Let`s assume I have the following string
0011NANA01NA0011NANANANA

My desired output:
'011000100011____', 
which means at the end of the string all of the NA should be replaced by space (I used '_' to indicate spaces).

AFAIK I should use gsub() to make this changes. I tried to use the following code`s without any success.

`gsub("NA", " ", "0011NANA01NA0011NANANANA")` -  which replaces all of the NAs with space.
`gsub("NA$", " ", "0011NANA01NA0011NANANANA")` - which replaces the last NA of the string with space.

This works fine if I have only one NA at the end of the string. But how can I change all of the 4 NA`s at the end of the string in this example?
Could someone help me out with this problem?
Thanks in advance for all kind of help!

Comment: I think the bigger question here is - how did your data end up looking like that?  Seems like something may have gone wrong earlier in your code.

Comment: Yes indeed this is not the most user friendly data frame :) but I have to deal with this one. The strings are correct results of previous operations.

Comment: Richard's point isn't whether the results you have are correct, but whether those operations should have been done in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This'll do it. But like Richard said, you may want to focus your efforts on earlier in the code, if it's in your power.

```
s <- "0011NANA01NA0011NANANANA"

#inner regex: find NA which is followed by
#  _only_ N or A until the string ends.
#  those are spaces.

#outer regex: replace remaining NA with 0
gsub("NA", "0", gsub("NA(?=[NA]*$)", " ", s, perl = TRUE))
# [1] "0011000100011    "
```

[Explore the more complicated regex here](https://regex101.com/r/xE8gD2/1)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another nested `gsub` where the first one replace the "NA" with space.  In the second `gsub`, we match one or more space (`\\s+`) at the end of the string (`$`).  By using `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)`, it force all the characters that are matched on the left are skipped and allow the second pattern to be matched (`\\s`) i.e. any space that are not at the end of the string and replace it will 0.

```
 gsub("\\s+$(*SKIP)(*F)|\\s", "0", gsub("NA", " ", s), perl=TRUE)
 #[1] "0011000100011    "
```

#### data

```
s <- "0011NANA01NA0011NANANANA"
```

Comment: could you explain? I don't know some of those tokens

Comment: Thx for your answer akrun!

Comment: @MichaelChirico  Sorry, I forgot to add the explanation before.